# For loop sending wrong value- twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to read different results from different entities in one twig page.
The first loop sends the right results but the second one sends the data from the first loop (Article)

twig code to read Article :

```
  {% for article in article %}     

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="card mb-0 item-card2-card">
                        <div id="image-slider" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style=" width:100%; height: 270px !important;">
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <img src={{ asset('uploads/' ~ article.image ) }} alt="img" class="cover-image" >
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev left-0" href="#image-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <i class="carousel-control-prev-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next right-0" href="#image-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <i class="carousel-control-next-icon fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="item-card7-overlaytext">
                                <h4 class="mb-0">${{article.prix}}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-card2-img1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gallery">
                                <span class="badge bg-dark-transparent6 text-white fs-14 font-weight-semibold2"><i class="fe fe-image "></i> 5</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-card2-icons">
                            <a href="#" class="item-card2-icons-l bg-primary"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="item-card2-icons-r bg-secondary"><i class="fa fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="item-card2">
                                <div class="item-card2-desc">
                                    <div class="item-card2-text">
                                        <a href="#" class="text-dark"><h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-3">   {{article.nom}}

                                            </h4></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="mb-0">{{article.description}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-footer d-flex">
                            
                            <div class="item-card2-rating mb-0 ml-auto">
                                <div class="star-ratings start-ratings-main clearfix d-inline-flex">
                                    <div class="stars stars-example-fontawesome stars-example-fontawesome-sm mr-2">
                                        <select class="example-fontawesome" name="rating" autocomplete="off">
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                            <option value="4" selected>4</option>
                                            <option value="5">5</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            {% endfor %}
```

Twig code to read Repas variables :

```
{% for repas in repas %}

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="item-card overflow-hidden mb-0">
                        <div class="item-card-desc">
                            <a href="{{ path('singlerepas_show', { 'id': repas.id }) }}"></a>
                            
                            <div class="card text-center overflow-hidden mb-0">
                                <div class="card-img">
                                    <img src="../../assets/images/locations/germany1.jpg" alt="img" class="cover-image">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-card-text text-left">
                                    <div class="star-ratings start-ratings-main clearfix">
                                        <div class="stars stars-example-fontawesome stars-example-fontawesome-sm text-left">
                                            <select class="example-fontawesome" name="rating" autocomplete="off">
                                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                                <option value="4" selected>4</option>
                                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <h4 class="mb-2">{{ repas.nom }}</h4>
                                    <small class="text-white"><i class="fe fe-map-pin"></i> 8 Cities  <i class="ml-3 fe fe-eye"></i> 140+ Tour Places </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            {% endfor %}
```

The issue is, that it reads Article entity in the second loop, I looked online but found nothing concrete.
I am pretty sure the problem isn't the controller or any other file, but maybe there is another way on how to write diffrent loops ? ?

Controller code :

```
    public function index(Request $reques): Response
{
    $Repository=$this -> getDoctrine () -> getRepository (repas::class);
    $repas= $Repository -> findAll();

    $Repository=$this -> getDoctrine () -> getRepository (article::class);
    $article= $Repository -> findAll();






    return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
        'repas' => $repas,
        'article'=>$article,


    ]);
```

I tried to dump the variable inside the loop in twig `{{ dump(article)}}`and `{{dump(repas)}}`

Comment: *"but the second one seconds the data from the first loop..."* ? by seconds the data, did you mean sends the data or what ?

Comment: sorry i meant send. basicall y it is not reading {{ for repas in repas }}  and it just showing me the data from Article still

Comment: did you try to dump the two variables ? That should help if you include the dumped data so we can investigate more easily.

Comment: yes I dumped both, I get the same result.
which is basically showing me what's inside Entity 'Article' ( id, nom, description, categorie, prix,image) 
when I dump repas, it shows the same result, which are for Article..

Comment: then they have been initialized by the same data i might guess, can you show us how you initialized each variable and also adding the dumped output to the question will surely help.

Comment: Alright so, it worked, i have no idea how honestly or what was the issue but it did.
but I added my controller code for you to see.

Comment: no magic in developement, so am dead sure you altered something related to how the data is being populated into tthe variables. Anyway, happy you managed to solve it.

Comment: I know but I literally did nothing. I just refreshed the page multiple times and there we go.. because it made no sense. the code works everywhere else

Comment: I didn't work with `Symphony` (am a `Laravel` boy btw) but if you put it like this I'd say it's related to some sort of a cache mechanism.

Comment: that's what I thought too.. 
I am planning to start my laravel journey as soon as I finish this school project.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If you dumped the variables in the controller itself, do they also contain the same variables (which would mean: this is not a Twig problem)?

Comment: initially I dumped the variables and they gave me the same result, both what was in Article.

Comment: however it seems the issue was a browser's cache issue, because I been working with that function elsewhere and it works good so it made no sense. I just closed the browser and restarted the symfony app and voila.. I know for sure the issue wasn't code-related

Comment: Why there is no pagination in repo query and OP is expecting doctrine to do it magically?? Also check for loop is  "for article in article" instead it should be something like "for article in articles" and passed right "articles" from controller and before anyone say, readability is one of the code quality every one should be practising.

Answer (score -1):

use in twig the plural (article**s**)

`{% for article in articles %}`

and return in controller too `articles`

```
$articles = $Repository -> findAll();

return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
    'articles'=>$articles,
]);
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't matter in twig [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/hihavx)

Comment: It just worked, apparently a cache issue with the browser. no idea.